# Print from chrome, automatically, using OS printer menu settings

Tags: macos, printing, google-chrome-extension, osx-snow-leopard

I have an extension running on Chrome with kiosk-printing on. I'm on OS X 10.6.8.

I want it to print a page via the extension, without any dialog.

This works fine with just `print()`, but chrome prints using settings other than my required preset (page size etc')

How can I make chrome use my required preset?

I've tried the following:

- Looking into where the presets and standard settings are saved according to this http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100125135830153. It seems that chrome doesn't use these settings.
- Using the CUPS UI to change the standard preset, but it seems chrome doesn't use these settings either.
- Using the disable-print-preview flag, but then the system dialog appears and I lose kiosk printing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a built in solution, ended up using an applescript to click the print button of the dialog.

Details here [How to use applescript to hit enter on system printing dialog box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212296/how-to-use-applescript-to-hit-enter-on-system-printing-dialog-box?noredirect=1#comment26746380_18212296)