# How to use applescript to hit enter on system printing dialog box?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, applescript, osx-snow-leopard

I want to print chrome windows automatically (no dialogs) if they fit some sort of URL pattern (e.g. are not of a given set of URLs).

Can you use apple script for that? Could someone share an example? (I do not own a mac so I can't really experiment myself)

Comment: What do you mean by "print chrome windows"?

Comment: So you want a script to go through all open chrome windows and if they are not on one of a specified list of pages you want to...open tabs? Open tabs of what? Condense all of the windows that apply into tabs?

Comment: I just wanted to check the current open tabs, and if they answer a certain condition, print them without dialog boxes. The accepted answer works for me with a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Ahh sorry, by print I was thinking output into the console (I've been doing too much python lately). Glad you got an answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
set i to 1
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    tell window 1
        repeat with t in tabs
            --if title of t starts with "Example" then
            if {"http://example.com/", "http://aa.com/"} does not contain URL of t then
                set active tab index to i
                tell t to print
                delay 1
                tell application "System Events"
                    click button "Print" of window 1 of process "Chrome"
                    --keystroke return
                end tell
            end if
            set i to i + 1
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Print is part of the standard suite in every app, it would reduce the chance of error if you used it