# Automatically print page when window.print() is called or press the print button on print dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, printing

I wanted to know if it was possible to automatically print a window when window.print() is called without having to open the print dialog box, and if not than if it was possible to press the print button automatically when the print dialog page opens using JavaScript. It is important that time and hassle for the user is saved and that they do not have to press print every time the script is ran. I have a one local printer connected to my laptop.

Comment: I doubt it's possible, it would be very annoying

Comment: [Print from chrome, automatically, using OS printer menu settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208970/print-from-chrome-automatically-using-os-printer-menu-settings)